# Hive sql loop through table comparing values

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table in hive that looks like the below

```
fruit           value
apple           2
apple           3
apple           4
plum            2
plum            3
plum            4
```

I want to loop through the table and compare the previous value and fruit and create a new column(total) based off of the loop. this would be the logic

```
if [fruit] = previous[fruit] then total = prev[fruit]
```

The new table should look like this

```
fruit       value      total
apple       2    
apple       3          2
apple       4          3
plum        2        
plum        3          2
plum        4          3
```

How can i achieve this using SQL in Hive?
Also i have ordered the results in my query so its grouped by fruit and ascending values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" row unless a column specifies the ordering.  Assuming you have such a column, then you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(value) over (partition by fruit order by ?) as prev_value
from t;
```

The `?` is for the name of the column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, you can artificially create an order by writing to a temp table like this:

```
create table #holding (rowid int identity, fruit varchar(max), value int)
insert #holding
select fruit, value from your table
order by fruit, value
```

This will recreate the order in the original table and allow you to do what Gordon said above